# Nativescript - Set Unsafe Text to Label

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm using nativescript core....

I have a label that I'm binding with text that comes from an api. The text that's coming from the api looks like this...

`This is some text &#xa; with a linebreak`

The label will display with a line break if hardcoded directly like this...

`<Label id="lyrics" text="This is some text &#xa; with a linebreak" verticalAlignment="top" horizontalAlignment="center" />`

But if you bind it through code it will not

`var label = view.getViewById(page, "lyrics"); 
 label.text = valueFromApi`

Is there any way to set encoded values like this to labels?

Comment: When you hard code it, it's XML so the encoded character works. When you bind it from model, it's JavaScript so you will have to take care of decoding.